# How to target a certain element in ul and li in javascript DOM without any IDs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a navigation bar with just javascript(without any CSS or HTML). I am wondering how can I target the second element of the array without any IDs. With the following code I am able to make the element "China" green. What I want to do now is, to make the element "United States" green. How do I do that?

```
var nav1 = document.createElement("div")
nav1.style.background = "Red";

var nav11 = document.createElement("ul");
nav1.appendChild(nav11);

var arr1 = ["Countries", "United States", "Canada", "India", "China"];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var nav111 = document.createElement("li");
    nav11.appendChild(nav111);
    nav111.innerHTML = arr1[i];
}
nav111.style.background = "Green";

document.body.appendChild(nav1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you will need to have at least a logic defined that determines when an element needs to be coloured green. I'd rather explain myself through examples, if your specs are to coloured strictly the 2nd element in the array, then simply track the 2nd interation in the `for` loop...

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var nav111 = document.createElement("li");
    nav11.appendChild(nav111);
    nav111.innerHTML = arr1[i];

   if(i == 1)
      nav111.style.background = "Green";
}
```

However, if the specs dictates that it depends on the item name..."United States", then change the condition expression to...

```
if(arr1[i] == 'United States')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move your line `nav111.style.background = "Green";` in for loop & every item will be green.

If you want this particular for `United States` you have to check with if condition if *`index is 1`* or *`text is United States`*.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var nav111 = document.createElement("li");
    nav11.appendChild(nav111);
    nav111.innerHTML = arr1[i];
    nav111.style.background = "Green";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a different approach. First, separate the logic from the data, think that the color is associated to the country, so you may want to have a collection of countries:

```
var countries = [
  { name: 'USA'
  , color: 'green'
, }
  { name: 'Canada'
  , color: 'red'
, }
  { name: 'India'
  , color: 'yellow'
, }
  { name: 'China'
  , color: 'blue'
  }
]
```

Then, your `for` loop is hardcoded, this is a bad idea `i<5`, you should compare the length like `i<coutries.length`, but you can also use `forEach`.

```
countries.forEach(function(country) {
  var li = document.createElement('li')
  li.textContent = country.name
  li.style.backgroundColor = country.color
  nav11.appendChild(li)
})
```

Comment: I would avoid the forEach loop as it is not supported by IE8 and below. Use a for loop instead.

Comment: If you change the `forEach` loop to a `for` loop you will get an upvote as your solution is so far the best.